# Fancybox does not work on live site but works locally

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using a fancybox demo (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) on my personal site. Everything works perfectly when I'm testing locally, but once I uploaded the site to be live, the fancybox feature is not working and instead brings you to a new page view the image.

This is the site I am referring to: http://colettemolleur.com/. Click on the image to see the issue I'm having. Also, I'm not forgetting to upload any of the js files, so I don't know why this is happening.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Colette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your path for `Bootstrap`, `main.js` and `query.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js` which return 404 not found on your page. I suspect the path are incorrectly setted.

In chrome, use the developer tools (using F12 or right click+ inspect element) to check for error on the page. I get 4 when opening your page.